# select row after update in mysql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, sql-update

How to select one row after update in one query with `PDO` and `PHP`?

like this:

```
function giftUpdate($username,$id,$date,$conn){
$update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE gifts SET used = 1 , user = :user , date = :date WHERE id = :id");
$update->bindParam("id" , $id );
$update->bindParam("date" , $date );
$update->bindParam("user" , $username );
$update->execute();
return $update ? true : false;
```

}

```
function giftGet($username,$currnetTime,$conn) {
$statment = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM gifts WHERE used = 0 ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$statment->execute();
$gift = $statment->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($gift){
    $voucher = $gift->code;
    $voucherid = $gift->id;
    $vouchertype = $gift->type;
    $voucherkey = $gift->keys;

    if($voucher){
       $giftUpdate = giftUpdate($username,$voucherid,$currnetTime,$conn);
       if($giftUpdate){
        useUpdate($username , $conn);
       }
    }
}

usleep(50000);
return $gift ? $gift : false;
```

}

After update I need select the same row to send it to user.

(i`am one table for vouchers list with 1000row and column 'used' with 0 by default  , and with user request i need in one query update this row to be used 1 and select this row.)

my problem in this functions is Some users will receive a duplicate vouchers And a code is assigned to several users.

guys ... for this case Is it possible to use the transaction method? Or do you suggest using a transaction at all?

**Edited:**

I eventually changed the code below, but I'm still in line :

SELECT id FROM gifts WHERE used = 0 ORDER BY `id` ASC limit 1 FOR UPDATE)");

**But when I put an id from the database instead of this code, it works!**

```
function giftGet($username, $currnetTime, $conn)
{
$uniqid = uniqid('vouchers_');
$update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE gifts SET used = 1, uniqueid =:uniqueid , user = :user , date = :date WHERE id = (
                          SELECT id FROM gifts WHERE used = 0 ORDER BY `id` ASC limit 1 FOR UPDATE)");
$update->bindParam("date", $currnetTime);
$update->bindParam("uniqueid", $uniqid);
$update->bindParam("user", $username);
$update->execute();
$updaterowCount = $update->rowCount();
if ($updaterowCount)
    {
    $statment = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM gifts WHERE uniqueid = :uniqueid ORDER BY `id` ASC");
    $statment->bindParam("uniqueid", $uniqid);
    $statment->execute();
    $gift = $statment->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $voucherid = $gift->id;
    if ($gift)
        {
        useUpdate($username, $voucherid, $conn);
        }
    }

return $gift ? $gift : false;
}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to select the row after updating it? If you are trying to make sure it was updated you can use `$statement->rowCount()` to see if your record was updated.

Comment: i`am one table for vouchers list with 1000row and column 'used' with 0 by default  , and with user request i need in one query update this row to be used 1 and select this row.

Comment: What about making sure that the voucher you hand out has not been used before? `"UPDATE gifts SET used = 1 , user = :user , date = :date WHERE id = :id AND used = 0"` - Afterwards you can check with `rowCount()` whether or not the voucher was successfully assigned.

Comment: guys ... for this case Is it possible to use the transaction method? Or do you suggest using a transaction at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would alter the table gifts and add a column uniqueid(varchar).

then use

```
$uniqid = uniqid('vouchers_');
```

and rewrite your update

```
"UPDATE gifts SET used = 1, uniqueid =:UNIQUEID , user = :user , date = :date WHERE id = (
SELECT id FROM gifts WHERE used = 0 ORDER BY `id` ASC limit 1 FOR UPDATE)";
```

now you can identify the updated record by uniqueid. 
In Your Code there is a time-gap between the select and the update. 2 or more users can start at the same time the select, recieve the same voucher before it is updated with used = 1

Comment: thanks for your response, whats your suggestion about this time-gap .

Comment: first call giftUpdate(...) with my update, return $uniqid and call giftGet($uniqueid,...) with SELECT * FROM gifts WHERE uniqueid =:UNIQUEID

Comment: Do you think that using a "transaction" is not a better fit for this?

Comment: a transaction doesnt change the behavior of a select statement, i dont see any benefit here in your case